# Gráficos no Libchart

Tags: php

Estou desenvolvendo uma apresentação no Libchart. Veja abaixo:

```
$dataSet->addPoint(new Point("Ensino Fundamental","16%"));
$dataSet->addPoint(new Point("Ensino Médio/Técnico","52%"));
$dataSet->addPoint(new Point("Graduação", "41%"));
$dataSet->addPoint(new Point("Pós/Especialização","2%"));
$dataSet->addPoint(new Point("Mestrado", "0%"));
$dataSet->addPoint(new Point("Doutorado", "0%"));
```

Até aqui tudo bem, porém quando troco 16% por 6% dá erro. Vejam abaixo:

Com 6% fica errado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com 16% fica certo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: possível duplicata de [Erro libChart PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/66073/erro-libchart-php)

Comment: Consegui resolver. O erro é simples. Quando os valores forem inferiores a 9, coloquem o zero antes do número. Coloquei 06 e funcionou.

Comment: Se possível coloque como resposta a resolução do problema. =)

Comment: qmechanik... realmente houve duplicata, pois eu estava no notebook quando criei o primeiro, porém houve um problema e tive que reiniciar o notebook, não reparei que foi publicado. Desculpe por isso. Como faço para excluir a duplicata?

Comment: Removi a duplicata.

Comment: Olá qmechanik. Como faço pra colocar a resposta como a resolução do problema. Obrigado

Comment: José, logo abaixo tem um campo que você pode usar para postar a resposta, depois de certo tempo, se possível, marque-a como aceita. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver. Basta trocar o 6% por 06%. Todos os números menores ou igual a 9, tem que colocar o 0 antes. Ex.:

```
$dataSet->addPoint(new Point("Ensino Fundamental","06%"));
```